# Web View not working in iOS

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, segue

I am new to Objective-C.

I have a table view populated with links that the user has added. When the user clicks on one of the cells in the table view, they are guided to a second view controller with a web view that displays the website of the link. However, when I run the app the web view appears blank. How do I fix this problem? There are no errors noted in the console either.

Table View .m

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showWebsite"]) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:cell.textLabel.text];
        NSString *string = url.absoluteString;
        SecondViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.url = string;
    }
}
```

Second View Controller .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.url stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: Is the URL nil ? Why don't you pass the URL rather than passing the absoluteString ? IS the webview connected in IB ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri because it is an incompatible pointer type, thats why I put the NSURL in an NSString. And yes the URL ends up being nil. I don't understand why because the url is the text in the cell (cell.textLabel.text). And yes, the web view is connected

Answer (score 0):

Can you try placing the 3 lines from the
- (void)viewDidLoad
to the
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
instead?

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the PrepareForSegue method. I have always used ViewDidLoad in the past and it has always worked.